# Cannot log a pointer C++

Tags: c++, arduino, c++-cli

I'm programming on Visual Studio 2017 and i'm fed up with an error which took my entire day.

More precisely, i'm working on an Serial Communication project.
The code will send on every port availiable (GetPortName()) a string.
I installed a log header (plog) which will log all actions.
For each port, the program will log ("Testing port" port).
The variable which stands for port is "s".
The problem is when i lauch : `LOGI << s;` everything mess up and got a big error.
I tried "&s" instead of simply "s" on LOGI and i have not got any error but there's an adress like 0059EBF0 instead of the port.
I search and research but found nothing.
Can someone help me please ?

Thanks

```
for each (String^ s in SerialPort::GetPortNames())
        {
            SerialPort^ mySerialPort = gcnew SerialPort();
            LOGI << &s;
            mySerialPort->PortName = s;
            mySerialPort->BaudRate = 115200;
            mySerialPort->Open();
            mySerialPort->Write("q");
            String^ incom = mySerialPort->ReadLine();
            if (incom == "Okay") {
                LOGI << "Tt va bien mon fwewe";
                setup = false;
            }
            mySerialPort->Close();
            _getch();
}
```

Comment: `String^` is not standard c++, but some dialect

Comment: I think the ^ stand for *

Comment: It's actually C++/CLI, `^` means reference to a managed (=CLI) object. Unless you need to do interop with unmanaged code and you actually know well both C++ and the .NET Framework I wouldn't recommend using it. If you want to use the .NET Framework use C#, it's way more convenient. If you want C++, use native C++, it's a language that is complicated enough even without the .NET interop subtleties.

Comment: I confirm that but, the library i need (system io port) is using the NET Framework. I didn't find other library which doesn't use it